# .NET core PublishSingleFile omiting version info

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm having problems getting the version information into the properties of an exe file being published with `dotnet publish`.

When running the following command (in docker using image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1`) the details tab of the exe file properties in windows is nearly empty:

```
dotnet publish test.sln -f netcoreapp3.1 -c Release -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:SelfContained=false -o /release/publish/win-x64
```

Publishing this from within Visual Studio (where MSBuild is used I guess) results in all version information shown in the details tab, including version number.

Also running `dotnet publish` without `PublishSingleFile` results in a dll having full version info but an exe (way smaller of course) without any of this info.

Version info is set in `.csproj` file like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there any way to get a single file exe with full version information from `dotnet publish`?

Comment: I want to know what is the full version you mentioned? Is the version defined in the .csproj file or the specific publish version?

Comment: @jack: can you tell me the difference? But independently of this I meant the version as written in .cspublish

Comment: OK, its a known (and open) issue when building win-x64 in Linux: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4127

Comment: I have this same issue on Windows 11, VS 2022. Any resolution?